# Angular display's literal in confirmation prompt

Tags: angularjs, syntax, prompt, confirmation

I'm creating a localization prompt

```
<a href='#' rel="nofollow"
 ng-click="
confirmClick('{{lang.shopping_cart.clear_sc_prompt}}') && 
deleteShoppingCart()" confirm-click>{{lang.shopping_cart.clear_shopping_cart}}</a>
```

But on-click it prompts the literal:

> {{lang.shopping_cart.clear_sc_prompt}}

How do I display this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide an expression inside `ngClick` directive, no need to interpolate it with `{{}}`:

```
ng-click="confirmClick(lang.shopping_cart.clear_sc_prompt) && deleteShoppingCart()"
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to put in literals,

```
confirmClick(lang.shopping_cart.clear_sc_prompt)
```